# Definition of transient state

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, definition, markov-chains

Consider the following definition

> **Transient States**
>
> It is often useful to talk about whether a process entering a state will ever return to this state. Here is one possibility.
>
> 1. A state is said to be a **transient** state if, upon entering this state, the process may never
>      return to this state again.
> 2. Therefore, state $i$ is transient if and only if there exists a state $j$
>      $( j \neq i)$ that is accessible from state $i$ but not vice versa, that is, state $i$ is not accessible from state $j$.
> 3. Thus, if state $i$ is transient and the process visits this state, there is a positive probability (perhaps even a probability of 1) that the process will later move to state $j$ and so will never return to state $i.$
>
> Consequently, a transient state will be visited only a finite number of times.

How is it that all 1., 2. and 3. are the same?

As far as I understand they are different except the later in case 1. which I think is the same as 2.

In 1. there is the posibility of visit a state $i$ and return to this or not to return to this. If the later, then is equivalent to case 2.

In 2. there is no chance to return to $i$ never.

In 3. there is the choice to return to $i$ and then never come back to $i$.

Comment: Here is the most common definition. Let $i$ be a state in the Markov chain and suppose the chain has initial state $X_0 = i$. Let $T_i$ be the first time the chain returns to $i$ (that is, $T_i \equiv \inf\{ t \geq 1 \colon X_t = i \}$. Then, $i$ is called *recurrent* if $\mathbb{P}(T_i < \infty) = 1$. Otherwise, $i$ is *transient*. Clearly, this conflicts with (1).

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo you can find this topics in Operational research book by Hillier

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo ooh ok. I will think twice the next time I use tags

Comment: @parsiad that definition is too formal I think

Comment: all conflicts with all  :/

Comment: That's not a reasonable complaint, in my opinion. The definition I gave is unambiguous. If you want your work to be meaningful, you need unambiguity.

Comment: @parsiad you're right, where is it from? and how would you read $\mathbb{P}(T_i < \infty) = 1$ ?

Comment: Most standard texts that cover Markov chains have this definition (e.g., Walsh, John B. *Knowing the odds: an introduction to probability*. Vol. 139. American Mathematical Soc., 2012.) How you read that is "the chain returns to state $i$ with probability one". It sounds to me like you should abandon the text you are reading and use a different one (Walsh's is good).

Comment: @parsiad Thank you. Yeah I should leave my current text. That book have a little bit of this and of that and ends up confusing the reader..